# Does the pressure in a pipe influence the mass flow?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, mass

A 50 MW generator cooled with hydrogen generates a power loss of 2.5 MW.
This heat output is dissipated by the gaseous hydrogen at a constant pressure of 0.98 bar. The hydrogen heats up from 15°C to 60°C.
1)What is the required mass flow rate m (So in kg/s) ?
2)Does the required mass flow change when the hydrogen is passed through the generator at double pressure and if so by what factor?
3)The generator is driven by a turbine and receives a mechanical power of 52.5MW from it. What is the efficiency of the generator?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this so far?

Comment: $$ U = m * c * (T2-T1)$$ I would answer the first question with the equation for heat and then just rearrange by mass flow .

With the second I am very unsure ...
In the caloric equation of state for ideal gases, the pressure does not actually occur and since I have to intercept the same heat here, I would say that nothing changes in the mass flow.
However, in the thermal equation of state for ideal gases pV=mRT the mass is dependent on the pressure. 

And to 3 I would divide the (maximum power - power loss) by the maximum power of the generator so 2.5 MW.

Answer (score 0):

The results of this analysis depend on how much the behavior of hydrogen at these pressures and temperatures deviates from ideal gas behavior (which prevails only at very low pressures).  The equation for the mass flow rate in this system must be expressed using the open system version of the first law of thermodynamics (in terms of enthalpy), not the closed system version (in terms of internal energy).  $$\dot{m}\Delta h=Q$$where h is the enthalpy per unit mass.  We can't use the heat capacity directly because it is a function of temperature and pressure. By applying Hess' law to case 1 (0.98 bars), we can write $$\Delta h(0.98)=h(65,98)-h(15,0.98)=-(h(15,98)-h(15,0))+C_p^{IG}(65-15)+(h(65,0.98)-h(65,0))$$where $$C_p^{IG}(65-15)=h(65,0)-h(15.0)$$with $C_p^{IG}$ representing the ideal gas heat capacity.  Similarly, for case 2 (1.96 bars), we can write $$\Delta h(1.96)=h(65,1.96)-h(15,1.96)=-(h(15,1.96)-h(15,0))+C_p^{IG}(65-15)+(h(65,1.96)-h(65,0))$$The change in enthalpy with pressure at constant temperature can be determined by integrating the equation:  $$\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial P}\right)_T=v-T\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\right)_P=-\frac{RT^2}{P}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial T}\right)_P$$

So the bottom line is that the required mass flow rate at 1.96 bars is a little different from the required mass flow rate at 0.98 bars.